# Angular 2 Fix dynamic Particles JS Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, particles.js

I am working on a web application with angular 2 v4 and I want to include different Particles.js dynamically using a parameter I want to load a specific particles format.

The problem is that this parameter comes from the database and I manage it through observables and therefore it is not possible to load it from the ngOnInit function or from the constructor.

Everything works fine and loads the documents correctly, the problem is that when I leave that route the error appears:

```
Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
```

Here I have some of my configuration

**angular-cli.json**

```
"scripts": [
        ...
        "../node_modules/particles.js/particles.js",
        ...
      ],
```

**login.ts**

```
declare var particlesJS: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
// Color variables----------------------------------------------------
    default = false;
    amber = false;
    green = false;
    red = false;
    blue = false;
    gray = false;
    white = false;
    purple = false;
    orange = false;
    lightBlue = false;
  // Color variables----------------------------------------------------

  clientConfig: any;
  constructor(public clientConfigService: ClientConfigService) {
        this.clientConfigService.readData().subscribe(data => {
          this.clientConfig = data;
          this.changeTheme(this.clientConfig);
        } );
      }
  ngOnInit() {}

  changeTheme(config: Client) {
    this.default = false;
    this.amber = false;
    this.green = false;
    this.red = false;
    this.blue = false;
    this.gray = false;
    this.white = false;
    this.purple = false;
    this.orange = false;
    this.lightBlue = false;
    switch (config.color) {
      case 'default': this.default = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/default-particles.json'); break;
      case 'amber': this.amber = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/amber-particles.json'); break;
      case 'green': this.green = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/green-particles.json'); break;
      case 'red': this.red = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/red-particles.json'); break;
      case 'blue': this.blue = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/blue-particles.json'); break;
      case 'gray': this.gray = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/gray-particles.json'); break;
      case 'white': this.white = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/white-particles.json'); break;
      case 'purple': this.purple = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/purple-particles.json'); break;
      case 'orange': this.orange = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/orange-particles.json'); break;
      case 'lightblue': this.lightBlue = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/light-blue-particles.json'); break;
      default: this.default = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/default-particles.json'); break;
    }
  }
}
```

**login.html**

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

this route belongs to **"localhost:4200/login"** and at this point, everything works fine and no error is in the console. The problem is when I go to another route **"localhost:4200/forgot"** for example (or any other). Just when I go to other route, this error appears in console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null
    at window.particlesJS (scripts.bundle.js:4114)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (scripts.bundle.js:4150)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.es5.js:3890)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:161)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (zone.js:144)
```

---

---

---

### UPDATE

This is all my HTML code, including the routing. This page displays in route http://localhost:4200/session/signin

So when I click the login button and go to any other route (in this case http://localhost:4200/dashboard) and the base component is destroyed... console displays the error

**Routing**

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', component: AdminLayoutComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [{ path: 'dashboard',  loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' }]
},
{
  path: '',
  component: AuthLayoutComponent,
  children: [{
    path: 'session',
    loadChildren: './session/session.module#SessionModule'
  }]
}];
```

**Login.html**

```
<div class="whitemask">
    <div id="particles-js" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class=" gradient-animated">
      <div class="session-wrapper" style="position: absolute;">

        <div class="mat-card-login">
          <div class="login-form">
            <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="off">
              <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around">
                <div class="pb-1">
                  <mat-form-field color="accent" class="login-input" style="width: 100%">
                    <input name="i-sl-li-lg-001" matInput placeholder="Cuenta"  [formControl]="form.controls['account']">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['account'].hasError('required') && form.controls['account'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Debe ingresar una cuenta válida.</mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="pb-1">
                  <mat-form-field color="accent" class="login-input" style="width: 100%">
                    <input name="i-sl-li-lg-003" matInput color="accent" [type]="passvisible" placeholder="Contraseña" [formControl]="form.controls['password']">
                    <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="visibePass()" style="cursor: pointer" [ngStyle]="{ 'color': passvisible === 'password' ? 'rgba(0,0,0,0.44)' : 'black' }">visibility</mat-icon>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['password'].hasError('required') && form.controls['password'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Debe ingresar una contraseña.</mat-error>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="showMessage" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="errortext" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: -15px">{{ error }}</div>
                <button id="b152" mat-raised-button class="login-button" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Iniciar sesión</button>

                <div style="padding-top: 10px" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
                    <a class="forgot" [routerLink]="['/session/forgot']">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Login.ts** Function On Submit

```
onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.form.controls['account'].value,
                           this.form.controls['password'].value).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.access_token) {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
          this.showMessage = false;
        } else {
          if (data.status) {
            switch (data.status) {
              case '401': this.error = 'Error'; break;
              case '402': this.error = 'User nor found'; break;
            }
          }
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.error = 'Login Error, try it later.';
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again by moving your code inside the constructure to ngAfterViewInit.

```
declare var particlesJS: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
// Color variables----------------------------------------------------
    default = false;
    amber = false;
    green = false;
    red = false;
    blue = false;
    gray = false;
    white = false;
    purple = false;
    orange = false;
    lightBlue = false;
  // Color variables----------------------------------------------------

  clientConfig: any;
  constructor(public clientConfigService: ClientConfigService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.clientConfigService.readData().subscribe(data => {
          this.clientConfig = data;
          this.changeTheme(this.clientConfig);
        } );
  }

  changeTheme(config: Client) {
    this.default = false;
    this.amber = false;
    this.green = false;
    this.red = false;
    this.blue = false;
    this.gray = false;
    this.white = false;
    this.purple = false;
    this.orange = false;
    this.lightBlue = false;
    switch (config.color) {
      case 'default': this.default = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/default-particles.json'); break;
      case 'amber': this.amber = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/amber-particles.json'); break;
      case 'green': this.green = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/green-particles.json'); break;
      case 'red': this.red = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/red-particles.json'); break;
      case 'blue': this.blue = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/blue-particles.json'); break;
      case 'gray': this.gray = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/gray-particles.json'); break;
      case 'white': this.white = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/white-particles.json'); break;
      case 'purple': this.purple = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/purple-particles.json'); break;
      case 'orange': this.orange = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/orange-particles.json'); break;
      case 'lightblue': this.lightBlue = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/light-blue-particles.json'); break;
      default: this.default = true; particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/data/default-particles.json'); break;
    }
  }
}
```

You receive this error because the html elements that particles.js is trying to reach have not yet been generated. Please check the [this document](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't work. Do you know any other way to fix this error?

Comment: I create example Stackblitz application and its worked. Please check it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vp3yzs